# Search for Row based on Column Value, Change Values of Row Found from Values in Input sheet- Google Apps Script (Sheets)

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to JavaScript... I have 2 spreadsheets created. 1 that has input values, and the 2nd is a target sheet where I want to update information.

I am searching through the target sheet with values from the input sheet with a column labeled "OpportunityID". Once the associated row is found, I want to update the target row with the values from the input sheet.

I've been able to search the target sheet with OpportunityID value from the input sheet and pull the values of columns in that specific row, but I am having trouble changing the values on the target sheet to the corresponding values on the input sheet.

Here is the code I have tried so far that pulls the appropriate information, but I need help resetting the values of that row:

```
function updateOpportunity() {

  // Get active spreadsheets and sheets
  var inputSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Search & Create New Records');
  var OppsAndContracts = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Opportunities & Contracts');
  var opportunityUpdateCopy = inputSheet.getRange('A8:Q8').getValues();
  Logger.log(opportunityUpdateCopy);


  //Search for Opportunities using OpportunityID
  var last=OppsAndContracts.getLastRow();
  var data=OppsAndContracts.getRange(1,1,last,17).getValues();// create an array of data from columns A through Q
  var opportunityID = updateSheet.getRange("A8").getValue();
  Logger.log(opportunityID);
  for(nn=0;nn<data.length;++nn){
    if (data[nn][0]==opportunityID){
      var OppID = (((data[nn][0])));
      var OppName = ((data[nn][1]));
      var AccountID = ((data[nn][2]));
      var AccountName = ((data[nn][3]));
      var OppOwner = ((data[nn][4]));
      var CloseDate = ((data[nn][5]));
      var Amount = ((data[nn][6]));
      var ProposalOwner = ((data[nn][7]));
      var Stage = ((data[nn][8]));
      var AeroServicesProducts = ((data[nn][9]));
      var MechServicesProducts = ((data[nn][10]));
      var ProjectStatus = ((data[nn][11]));
      var PaymentIssues = ((data[nn][12]));
      var UniquePaymentTerms = ((data[nn][13]));
      var PaymentTerms = ((data[nn][14]));
      var ProposalNumber = ((data[nn][15]));
      var ContractNumber = ((data[nn][16]));} ;

OppsAndContracts.getRange([data]).setValues(opportunityUpdateCopy);    

  }
```

I've also tried getting the cell reference of the cells in the row with the corresponding OpportunityID and setting them with the values from the input sheet, but that hasn't worked either.

Any help or advice is much appreciated!

Comment: You can't define a range like this `OppsAndContracts.getRange([data])`. I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly, maybe you want to do this instead? `OppsAndContracts.getRange(1,1,last,17).setValues(opportunityUpdateCopy)`

Comment: Thanks for the input, Diego. I'm trying to get the range of the data that was pulled from the search using OpportunityID. How would you suggest doing that?

Comment: Without recreating your spreadsheet, it's difficult to confirm, but looks like you need to use the `nn` value when you have a match. So try something like `OppsAndContracts.getRange(nn+1, 1, 1, 17).setValues(opportunityUpdateCopy);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `nn` value to select the range when there's a match, since `nn` is effectively your row index.

```
function updateOpportunity() {
  // Get active spreadsheets and sheets
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var updateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Update Sheet"); // You didn't have this defined, so I added
  var inputSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Search & Create New Records');
  var OppsAndContracts = ss.getSheetByName('Opportunities & Contracts');
  var opportunityUpdateCopy = inputSheet.getRange('A8:Q8').getValues();

  //Search for Opportunities using OpportunityID
  var last = OppsAndContracts.getLastRow();
  var data = OppsAndContracts.getRange(1,1,last,17).getValues(); // create an array of data from columns A through Q
  var opportunityID = updateSheet.getRange("A8").getValue();
  for (var nn = 0; nn < data.length; ++nn) {
    if (data[nn][0] == opportunityID) {
      OppsAndContracts.getRange(nn + 1, 1, 1, 17).setValues(opportunityUpdateCopy);    
    }
  } 
}
```

*(I removed a bunch of the code that was irrelevant to your question.)*

Comment: Thanks, Diego! I will give this a try and comment below if it works out for me.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much for your help. I've been laboring over this for days now, and didn't want to post anything until I had exhausted all my options. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @NathanKittrell Great! Since it worked, please consider marking the answer as accepted and upvoting :)

Comment: I'll do both! Thanks again!